# How do I Import A textfile into javaDB?

Tags: java, javadb

I was wondering how do I import contents from a texfile into a database (javaDB).This is the code that I have however I receive an error upon execution. I would also like to state that the primary key of this table is auto incremented.

```
CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_IMPORT_TABLE 
(null,'EXPENDITURE','C:\Users\Me\Desktop\textforimport.txt',null,null,null,0);
// This is my import code
```

//This is my error

```
Executed successfully in 0.003 s.
Line 1, column 1

Error code 30000, SQL state 38000: The exception 'java.sql.SQLException: 
Attempt to modify an identity column 'EXPENDITURE_ID'.' was thrown while evaluating an expression.

Error code 99999, SQL state 42Z23: Attempt to modify an identity column 'EXPENDITURE_ID'. 
Line 4, column 1

Execution finished after 0.003 s, 1 error(s) occurred.
```

// Code for creating table

```
create table Expenditure (
Expenditure_ID integer not null primary key generated always as identity (start with 1,increment by 1),
Expenditure_Description varchar (75) not null,
Expense double not null,
Expense_Date date not null
);
```

Now I am no expert in java but am wondering if anyone call help me with this. I would be grateful. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just change the declaration of your **Expenditure_ID** to **"GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY"**,

> An identity column that is GENERATED BY DEFAULT will only increment
>   and use the default value on insertions when no explicit value is
>   given. Unlike GENERATED ALWAYS columns, you can specify a particular
>   value in an insertion statement to be used instead of the generated
>   default value.
>   [source](http://web.mit.edu/course/13/13.715/jdk1.6.0_18/db/docs/html/ref/ref-single.html#crefsqlj95081)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it is a simple SQL problem, not a java problem.

Since the column **Expenditure_ID** was created as "**primary key generated always as identity**", javaDB will generate it for you automatically. And, when you try to manipulate an identity column, you will receive the *Attempt to modify an identity column* error.

You can try 2 approaches:

1) Remove from **textforimport.txt**, the column/data **Expenditure_ID**. Just import **Expenditure_Description**, **Expense** and **Expense_Date**. As I said, javaDB will assign an ID to each row.

***or***

2) If you need to define the **Expenditure_ID** by yourself, change the **Expenditure_ID** column in Expenditure table. Try to create it only with "**integer not null**" (without the primary key stuff).